# with the problem of scrapy, how to combine the printing results of two ''title"

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

how to combine the printing results of two 'titles'?
why only the second title will be displayed in the print result

```
def parse(self, response):
    li_list = response.xpath("//div[@class='main']/div[2]/ul/li")
    for li in li_list:
        item = MyspiderItem()
        item['title'] = li.xpath("./h2/a[2]/text()").get()
        item['title'] = li.xpath("./div[2]/h2/a[2]/text()").get()
        print(item)
```

Comment: Please provide your code in text in your question

Comment: why not just make `item['title]` the combination of those 2 strings instead of calling it twice on separate line ?

Comment: how to make item['title'] as a combination of 2 strings

Answer (score 0):

You assign the value of `item[title]` 2 time so it only print the second one. To get both title, use `item[title]` as a list or create a 2 variable for 2 titles.

Comment: but it only printed one of them result,

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of titles:

```py
item['title'] = [li.xpath("./h2/a[2]/text()").get()]
item['title'].append(li.xpath("./div[2]/h2/a[2]/text()").get())
```

Comment: The item contain 2 types，None and str, so can not add

Comment: I didn't understand, I updated `+=` to `append()` you can append everything to list, if problem is something else please explain further.